# Lucene.net - How to search alternate index keys or alternate word combinations?

Tags: asp.net, language-agnostic, lucene.net

In my Lucene index I have the following keys

> id
>   fullText
>   user
>   date

I've got the fullText search working pretty good using the following method.

```
Public Function ReadIndex(ByVal q As String, ByVal page As Integer?) As Domain.Pocos.LuceneResults Implements ILuceneService.ReadIndex
    ''# A timer variable to determine now long the method executes for
    Dim tStart As DateTime = DateTime.Now

    ''# Creates a container that we use to store all of the result ID's
    Dim IDList As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)

    ''# First we set the initial page number. 
    ''# If it's null, it means it's zero
    If page Is Nothing Then page = 0

    ''# [i] is the variable we use to extract the appropriate (needed)
    ''# documents from the results. Its initial value is the page number
    ''# multiplied by the number of results we want to return (in our
    ''# case 10). The [last] variable is used to stop the while loop at
    ''# the 10th record by simply adding 9 to the [i] variable.
    Dim i = page * 10
    Dim last As Integer = i + 9

    ''# Variables used by Lucene
    Dim reader As IndexReader = IndexReader.Open(luceneDirectory)
    Dim searcher As IndexSearcher = New IndexSearcher(reader)
    Dim query As Query = New TermQuery(New Term("fullText", q.ToLower))

    ''# We're using 10,000 as the maximum number of results to return
    ''# because I have a feeling that we'll never reach that full amount
    ''# anyways.  And if we do, who in their right mind is going to page
    ''# through all of the results?
    Dim topDocs As TopDocs = searcher.Search(query, Nothing, 10000)
    Dim doc As Document = Nothing

    ''# loop through the topDocs and grab the appropriate 10 results based
    ''# on the submitted page number
    While i <= last AndAlso i < topDocs.totalHits
        doc = searcher.Doc(topDocs.scoreDocs(i).doc)
        IDList.Add(doc.[Get]("id"))
        i += 1
    End While

    ''# Self explanitory
    searcher.Close()
    Dim EventList As List(Of Domain.Event) = EventService.QueryEvents().Where(Function(e) (IDList.Contains(e.ID))).ToList()

    Dim tStop As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim LucienResults As New Domain.Pocos.LuceneResults With {.EventList = EventList,
                                                              .ExecuteTime = (tStop - tStart),
                                                              .TotalResults = topDocs.totalHits}

    Return LucienResults
End Function
```

Now a problem I'm having is figuring out how to add user and date search to the method.

basically, if I do a search for "some event", the results are displaying perfectly.  However if I do a search for `user:joe` or `date:12/07/2100`, I don't get any results.

Also, if I have the phrase `the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs`, and I search for `brown fox`, I **will** get the index result, but if I search for `quick fox`, I **wont** get results. Basically I'd like to split the string on all spaces and search each word individually.

What do I need to add to this method to enable searching on specific keys and alternate word combinations?

Comment: note: my example is in VB, but I can deal with C# too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically searching for "brown fox" and "quick fox" as one single token. You probably want to either split on whitespaces and build a BooleanQuery with containing several  TermQuery fields, or just throw your string at the QueryParser.

The syntax "user:joe" syntax you describe is what the default QueryParser will parse into a new TermQuery(new Term("user", "joe")), which is what you want. Your current solution will search for a single "user:joe" token, which most analyzer will split up into two tokens, so you will never get a match with those analyzers.

Also, cant you tell your IndexSearcher.Search to stop at the last index you'll be reading, instead of 10000?

And while at it, don't read document instances using IndexSearcher.Doc if you're only interested in one field. Use the FieldCache which will keep an in-memory cache (by weakly referenced index segment readers) which will allow you quick lookups of single termed fields.

And finally, look into which analyzer you're using. Some are specific to other languages, some have synonym or stemming support, etc. Things that [usually] makes a search easier to work with.

Comment: this is a lot of really great info. Now I have to mull over it and ask more questions. This is my first time working with Lucene.Net

Comment: ok, got the query parser working. Question time... 1) tell "Search" to stop at last index... how can I do this? 2) FieldCache... how does that work? 3) I'm using StandardAnalyzer. What other analyzer should I be looking at?

Comment: I looked at the code again. I am stopping at the last index in the while loop so long as the last index is < 10000.

Comment: 1) searcher.Search(query, Nothing, last), 2) var ids = FieldCache_Fields.Default.GetStrings(reader, "id"); var id=ids[documentId]. However, the FieldCache is built around single readers, so you should pass them instead of the topmost one. Perhaps not useful in your case, this is a more advanced api. 3) StandardAnalyzer works for many cases, just make sure you use it at search-time with your QueryParser too.